# Cant remove file using os.remove

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, file-management

Having some problems with os.remove() at the moment. The file is not open, I have full permissions to edit and remove the file (and can do so outside of python) however access is denied from inside python itself. Is there something wrong with the code or could it be an issue within spyder itself?

EDIT: Updated with traceback
EDIT2: I just deleted a few folders manually and the rest ran fine, Im not sure what the problem what but atleast it works now!

```
import os
import traceback

rootDir = r"......"
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
 for filename in fileList:
        try:
            if filename[0:3] == "New":
                if (filename[3:] in fileList):
                    path = os.path.join(rootDir, filename[3:])
                    os.remove(path)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
            errorlist.append(filename)
__________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 31, in <module>
    os.remove(item)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '...'
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback for the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your directories structure, but there is maybe some relative dir issue when joining `path = os.path.join(rootDir, filename[3:])` ?

If not, can you copy your exception trace ?

Comment: Paths are correct, printed them all out typed into the windows explorer bar worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions first.

```
os.chmod(filePath, 0777)
os.remove(filePath)
```